# returning str vs. str.substr(0,str.size()) gives me different outputs in leetcode

Tags: c++, string

I just solved https://leetcode.com/problems/push-dominoes/.

My code is

```
class Solution {
public:

    string pushDominoes(string dominoes) {
        string res(dominoes.size(), ' ');
        dominoes = 'L' + dominoes + 'R';

        int l = 0;
        for(int r = 1; r < dominoes.size(); r++)
        {
            if(dominoes[r] != '.')
            {
                //check which case we have [L...R], [R....L] [L.....L]  [R...R]
                if(l != 0) res[l-1] = dominoes[l]; 
                if(r != dominoes.size() - 1) res[r-1] = dominoes[r];

                if(dominoes[l] == dominoes[r])
                {
                    for(int i = l; i <= r; i++) 
                        if(i > 0) res[i-1] = dominoes[r];
                }
                else if(dominoes[l] == 'L' && dominoes[r] == 'R')
                    for(int i = l+1; i < r; i++) res[i-1] = '.';
                else if(dominoes[l] == 'R' && dominoes[r] == 'L')
                {
                    if((l+r)%2 == 0) 
                    {
                        auto mid = (l+r)/2;
                        res[mid-1] = '.';
                        for(int i = l+1; i < mid; i++) res[i-1] = 'R';
                        for(int i = mid+1; i < r; i++) res[i-1] = 'L';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        auto mid = (l+r)/2;
                        for(int i = l+1; i <= mid; i++) res[i-1] = 'R';
                        for(int i = mid+1; i < r; i++) res[i-1] = 'L';
                    }
                }

                l = r;
            }
        }

        return res;
        // return res.substr(0, res.size());
    }
};

int main( ) 
{ 
   Solution soln;

   cout << soln.pushDominoes(".L.R.") << endl;
}
```

For one of the test cases, where the input is ".L.R." leetcode states that my output is "LL.RRRLLRRLL.." when I use `return res`. The answer is supposed to be "LL.RR". But I printed out `res` and it's indeed "LL.RR" and size 5.

If I change my code to return `return res.substr(0, res.size())` instead of `return res`, I get the correct solution. I'm perplexed as to why this is occuring when these 2 return statements should be identical?

I also ported the code over and compiled it on my computer, and I get the correct solution. This makes me wonder if there's some differences in how my code is handled between different C++ compilers, or if Leetcode might have some issues for this particular problem. Any advice?

Comment: You could have an outbreak of Undefined Behaviour elsewhere in the code that just comes out differently on the judge's computer. Maybe you accidentally stomped the terminating null somewhere. See what happens if you print out `res.c_str()`. Also worth doing to test is replace all of the operator `[]` uses with calls to `at` and see if the program throws an exception over a bounds check.

Comment: Side note: You should also provide the driver you're using to invoke this class. The easier you make things for folks to run your code the better. You get more eyes and lower chances of folks writing their own driver and changing the results. The more we have to change, the more likely we are to accidentally fix the problem or introduce another one.

Comment: Thanks @user4581301. I'll check. I also noticed something strange in the code in that if I remove the {} on the first `if` condition check, I start getting unexpected behavior.

Comment: I just checked res.c_str() and it gives "LL.RRR" instead of "LL.RR"

Comment: Looks like something's going out of range

Comment: I see the same output. Replacing the `[]`s with `at` I get a thrown exception. The code goes out of bounds somewhere.

Comment: @user4581301 Found the issue. it's inside the first conditional. I have a question. Why did you suggest to print out `res.c_str()`? Under which situations will this be different from the underlying `std:string`?

Comment: "LL.RRRLLRRLL.." and "LL.RR" are identical up to the size of the expected string length. This looks a lot like the terminating null had been overwritten. Printing a `string` often (and is probably required to. You can have nulls in a `string`)  terminates based on the `string`'s prerecorded length, not where the terminating null is. Printing it as a character array will show this. Odds are good that either the judge prints the C-string instead of the `string` to catch mistakes like this or they just use the same driver logic for the C and C++ versions.

Comment: [Looked it up](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt). `<<` of a `std::string` is required to stop at length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string res(dominoes.size(), ' ');
```

Sets the size of `res` to that of `dominoes` and this size is never changed. `res` can never be larger than `dominoes`. With input of ".L.R.", `dominoes`'s length is 5 . `res` is length 5.

```
dominoes = 'L' + dominoes + 'R';
```

Changes the size of `dominoes` to 7.

```
for (int r = 1; r < dominoes.size(); r++)
```

iterates `r` from 1 to 6.

Aside: When ever I see a `<=` in a `for` loop I stop for a longer look. It's wrong far more often than it is right.

In this case it seems to be only sort of wrong, allowing

```
for (int i = l; i <= r; i++)
    if (i > 0) res[i - 1] = dominoes[r];
```

to iterate `i` from `l` to `r`. Since `r` can be 6, `i` can be 6. That means

```
    if (6 > 0) res[6 - 1] = dominoes[6];
```

is possible.  This resolves to

```
    res[5] = dominoes[6];
```

and `res[5]` is not valid. Writing there invokes undefined behaviour, and in this case it appears to overwrite the null terminator of the c-style string backing the `string`.

Another aside: Avoid using `l` as a variable name. It looks too much like `1` and leads to bugs or misreading of the code.

To fix, you could expand the logic of `if (i > 0)` into `if (i > 0 && i-1 < res.size())` to filter out this problem, but you're better off reworking or replacing the algorithm so that you never find yourself in this situation.